# using java native method

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am creating a java program using native keyword.

class- HelloWorld.java is source code ,after compiling  , i generate a HelloWorld.h file.

and then in NetBeans I create  a c file , in which a include jni.h  header file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloWorld.h"

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
 Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return;
 }
```

but when i buld the projet then this error come

> HelloWorld.c:3:24: HelloWorld.h: No such file or directory
>   HelloWorld.c:10:3: warning: no newline at end of file

i put the HelloWorld.h file in surce files  folder

Comment: Do you have the native code in a separate C++ project within NetBeans?

Comment: You need to somehow point the JVM at your native library.  I forget how this is done in later JVMs, though.

Comment: @HotLicks This is a C compiler error. Nothing to do with the JVM yet.

Comment: You need to point your build tool at the H file path.